# How to generate two random points when a button is pressed

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, button

I want to plot two random points when a user presses a button. I have done some work but nothing happens when the button is pressed. The points remain at their current locations.

My code is as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pts = {{5, 1}, {3, 2}}},
  {
   Graphics[{
     Purple, PointSize[0.02], Point[Dynamic[pts[[1]]]],
     Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[Dynamic[pts[[2]]]],
     If[visualCheck == True, {Black, Circle[CenterPoint, radius]}, {}
      ]
     },
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large]
   }
  ](*DynamicModule*),
 
 (*Controllers*)
 Button["Click", pts = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[-10, 10], 2], 2]],
 {{CenterPoint, {1, 1}}, Locator},
 {{radius, 2, Style["Radius of the Circle", 12, Black]}, 1, 8, Slider},
 {{visualCheck, False, Style["Visual Check", 12, Black]}, {True, 
   False}, Checkbox}
 
 ]
```

*I want to change the `Black` and `Purple` points when the button is pressed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: why are using `DynamicModule` inside `Manipulate` for?? `Manipulate` itself is  `DynamicModule`  You making things way too complicated. If you want I can show you how to **I want to plot two random points when the user press a button** but I can not follow your code as is. I have to write new one without dynamicmodule inside manipulate.

Comment: I'm "new" to mathematica, I did not know that Manipulate itself is a DynamicModule thanks for letting me know. if you can show me how you would do it, it will be great

Answer (score 3):

Here is basic implementation. My advice, always start simple and when it is working, you can add more features.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{pt1 = pt[[1]], pt2 = pt[[2]]},
  Grid[{
       {pt},
       {Graphics[{{Red,PointSize[0.05],Point[pt1]}, {Blue,PointSize[0.05], Point[pt2]}},
        PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
      Axes -> True,
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]}}
    ]
  ]
 ,
 Grid[{{Button["Click", pt = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[-10, 10], 2], 2]]}}],
 {{pt, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {pt}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!